# Python regex sub confusion

Tags: python, regex

There are four keywords: `title`, `blog`, `tags`, `state`
Excess keyword occurrences are being removed from their respective matches.

**Example:**
`blog: blog state title tags and` returns `state title tags and` instead of

`blog state title tags and`
The `sub` function should be matching `.+` after it sees `blog:`, so I don't know why it treats `blog` as an exception to `.+`

**Regex:**

```
re.sub(r'((^|\n|\s|\b)(title|blog|tags|state)(\:\s).+(\n|$))', matcher, a)
```

**Code:**

```
def n15():
    import re
    a = """blog: blog: fooblog 
state: private
title: this is atitle bun
and text"""
    kwargs = {}
    def matcher(string):
        v = string.group(1).replace(string.group(2), '').replace(string.group(3), '').replace(string.group(4), '').replace(string.group(5), '')
        if string.group(3) == 'title':
            kwargs['title'] = v
        elif string.group(3) == 'blog':
            kwargs['blog_url'] = v
        elif string.group(3) == 'tags':
            kwargs['comma_separated_tags'] = v
        elif string.group(3) == 'state':
            kwargs['post_state'] = v
        return ''
    a = re.sub(r'((^|\n|\s|\b)(title|blog|tags|state)(\:\s).+(\n|$))', matcher, a)
    a = a.replace('\n', '<br />')
    a = a.replace('\r', '')
    a = a.replace('"', r'\"')
    a = '<p>' + a + '</p>'
    kwargs['body'] = a
    print kwargs
```

**Output:**

```
{'body': '<p>and text</p>', 'post_state': 'private', 'blog_url': 'foo', 'title': 'this is a bun'}
```

Edit:
**Desired Output:**

```
{'body': '<p>and text</p>', 'post_state': 'private', 'blog_url': 'fooblog', 'title': 'this is atitle bun'}
```

Comment: Should it be look for multiple lines or duplicate in each line.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace(string.group(3), '')
```

is replacing all occurrences of 'blog' with '' .

Rather than try to replace all the other parts of the matched string, which will be hard to get right, I suggest capture the string you actually want in the original match.

```
r'((^|\n|\s|\b)(title|blog|tags|state)(\:\s)(.+)(\n|$))'
```

which has `()` around the `.+` to capture that part of the string, then

```
v = match.group(5)
```

at the start of `matcher`.